# How can I tell the PHP to save a file in a specific folder when using $_POST to attribute the filename?

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble getting my script to save a file in a particular folder, normally the syntax would call for quotes around the entire path but because I'm using $_POST to name the file it just doesn't work out that way.  So far this is what I have.

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','on'); ?><?php

$fileName= fopen("Submissions/".$_POST['first_name'],'w');
$data= "";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= str_replace("_"," ",$key).":\n\n ". $value."\n\n\n\n"; preg_replace("/[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]/", "_", $value);
}

fwrite($fileName, $data);
fclose($fileName);


?>
```

Comment: I really hope that you're going to do some validation of that $_POST before using it to create a filename...

Comment: **Danger!** Your code is vulnerable to directory traversal attacks. Attackers could supply absolute or relative parent (`..`) paths to make your program overwrite important system files. You need to apply some escaping to all user input before passing it off as part of a structured string.

Comment: I appreciate the concern and I'm there's more I want to add to this code, I'm just taking it one thing at a time, I have a preg_replace script I'm going to add in.  That's sufficient enough right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems. First, you have syntax errors. Second, you have serious security vulnerabilities.

Let's start with the first syntax errors. This line:

```
$fileName= fopen(Submissions/$_POST['first_name'],'w');
```

Is invalid. You want to use string concatenation, like this:

```
$fileName= fopen("Submissions/" . $_POST['first_name'],'w');
```

But that's a huge security vulnerability. If `$_POST['first_name']` is something bad like `../../../etc/passwd`, you could be in for a world of hurt.

Then there's this:

```
fwrite(Submissions/$fileName, $data);
```

That's invalid syntax (again, string concatenation) and, again, insecure. It's also just wrong. You need a file resource, not a path name, as the first parameter.

In both of these places, ***you must validate the data before using it this way.*** Otherwise, expect to get hacked repeatedly.

Comment: ok that works great!!!!.  I updated it with a preg_replace, I was going to get to that but I was just taking the script one step at a time.  Is the one I added secure enough?

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq glad to help! The regex you posted should be enough, but you're applying it to the wrong data. You need to apply it to `$_POST['first_name']`, which is the part you inject into `fopen()`. I would go ahead and disallow (replace) spaces, as well.